Video of switch kick without follow through?
Approximately 1.5 years ago, I asked about practising a switch kick without a bag (here).  Several answers were to be disciplined enough to not follow through with the kick.  I find that the switch kick gives a lot of wind-up, so it's extremely hard to not follow through in the air.  However, I've tried to keep an open mind, working it into my roster of routines, which means I rotate to it once in a while.  It hasn't gotten any easier.  I searched without success for any video of a switch kick without a bag and without follow through.  I was wondering if anyone is aware of such a video.  It would certainly assure me that it is practical.  Thanks.

We were actually doing this in Capoeira practice last night, but we're a relatively non-contact group, so we do a lot of training on how to stop kicks (or at least heavily reduce the force) for if the other player doesn't dodge in time, so I don't know how useful it would be for you.

It'd be helpful to see a video of a switch-kick in the air (no target) and no follow through.  For those many times when I'm just drilling in my living room.  It just seems implausible when I try it.  I don't mean a video of your class necessarily, but anywhere online.

I'll try to upload a video tonight. :) It could even be that we're talking different techniques, but I watched the videos you posted, and it looks about right. We generally call that "troca, martello", but that's really just Portuguese for "exchange, hammer", the latter of which is the term for a roundhouse.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything under Google searches for either terms here and here.  Looking forward to anything that you can post.  Thanks.

Sorry, horribly absent minded, currently out of the house.

No worries.  You're under no obligation.  I suspect that due to the windup of a switch kick, it's not practical to practice combinations without a physical target/pad/bag.  Hence, the two combinations cited here can't be practiced outside of a training club/school or without some home equipment.
